# Remove Prefix from all file in current folder as well as files in subfolder windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

i am trying to remove prefix from all files in current folder and subfolders
i tryed following code which work only for current folder

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%F in (*) do (
  set "FN=%%F"
  set "FN=!FN:~15!"
  ren "%%F" "!FN!"
)
goto :eof
```

Please Help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s') do (
    set "fname=%%~nxa"
    set "fpath=%%~dpa"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:~15!"
    ren "!fpath!!fname!" "!nname!"
    endlocal
)
```

This is the safe way to preserve exclamation marks.

Comment: It does work, but it renames itself if it is in the same folder tree.  Like the previous renaming solution, add `pushd "c:\myfolder\"` (with your main folder in it) to the top and launch it from another folder.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows 7, you could try this:

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c ren @file @fname"
```

It took me a bit of time to find, but suddenly I realised that the batch file was not working because it had renamed itself!.

If this becomes an issue you could try naming the batch file `zzzzzzzzz.bat` which I think would prevent it from renaming itself first.

Mona

Comment: It will still get renamed as it is in the top level folder.  It doesn't remove the prefix, and it doesn't handle files in folders, and it renames folder names.  Apart from all that it's fine. ;)

Comment: it's usefull for renaming folder but not for removing prefix of all files from current dir and subdir

Comment: I had the benefit of reading and answering the previous post of this user, where the task was to add a prefix to all files in a tree.  Now he wants to remove that prefix.

Comment: yes bro i'm really thankfull for your help i just want to know the viseversa solution that's all

Comment: Mona, you didn't test this in a folder with subdirectories (with periods in the name) and files in a tree.

Comment: @foxidrive I tested it with files in a tree but not with subdirectories with periods in it, but that can be fixed with: `forfiles /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE ren @file @fname"` and that should work fine.

Comment: It tries to rename files in a subdirectory using the filename only.  How can that possibly work?  You haven't actually realised that the task is to remove the leading 15 characters from each filename.  Your code output has no resemblance to the desired task.